# Raspberry Pi Zero interference between onboard usb and plugged-usb connection

Tags: raspberry-pi, usb, zero

Is it possible to wire a wifi dongle directly using the PP-ports on the backside of the Zero to the pi's USB (described in [Hackaday Project](http://hackaday.com/2015/11/28/first-raspberry-pi-zero-hack-piggy-back-wifi/)) and also use the unused USB-Port for another device?
Or do they interfere?

Comment: Interesting question -- don't know the answer, but I wonder if a USB hub would solve the problem for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I just tried it by myself figuering out that it won't work. 
Connecting the data-wires parallel to another device via usb hangs up the kernel.